# where to find a small example/demo on how to create a LINQ Provider?

Tags: linq, iqueryable

Hi i was wondering if you have had seen a quick demo on creating a LINQ Provider.

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these resources:

- [Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx)
- [Linq Provider Basics](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/LINQProviderBasics.aspx)
- [Writing Custom Linq Provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2007/10/04/writing-custom-linq-provider.aspx)
- Good examples:

  - [Linq to Twitter](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToTwitter)
  - [Linq to ActiveDirectory](http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoAD)
  - [Linq to SharePoint](http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoSharePoint)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

http://www.codeplex.com/IQToolkit